# Executing oracle job serially

Tags: oracle11g, jobs

I need to execute a sub procedure in a parent procedure. This sub procedure is independent of the parent and need to be executed parallelly.
To achive parallel processing i am trying to use dbms job. I am submitting a job in my parent procedure to call sub process ie update_pricerange();.

DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(99,'update_pricerange(' || num_exchng_rate || ');', sysdate)

Here I have to execute a job only once so, not specifying the refresh interval. But here problem can arrise if i call my parent procesure from multiple sessions there is a probability that the same job getting called simultaneously and if more than one instance of update_pricerange(); get executed parallelly then it might cause deadlock or dirty data update.

So i want to ask whether I can execute this job serially so that update_pricerange() would be called serially and also in the sequence it is being called.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Does it boil down to "can I ensure that at most one instance of `update_pricerange` is running at any point in time?"

Comment: Yes justin that is what I want

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that `update_pricerange` is not being executed multiple times simultaneously, the simplest option is to use the `dbms_lock` package to create and acquire a user-defined lock in `update_pricerange`.  So, for example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_pricerange
AS
  l_lock_name    varchar2(30) := 'MY_LOCK_NAME';
  l_lock_handle  varchar2(128);
  l_status       integer;

  <<current declarations>>
BEGIN
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique( l_lock_name,
                             l_lock_handle );
  l_status := dbms_lock.request( l_lock_handle );
  IF( l_status = 1 )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Timeout waiting for ' || l_lock_name );
  ELSIF( l_status = 2 )
  THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20002, 'Deadlock waiting for ' || l_lock_name );
  ELSIF( l_status = 3 )
  THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20003, 'Parameter error waiting for ' || l_lock_name );
  ELSIF( l_status = 5 )
  THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20005, 'Illegal lock handle ' || l_lock_name );
  END IF;


  <<do stuff>>

  dbms_lock.release( l_lock_handle );
END;
```

Any time this procedure is called simultaneously in different sessions, the second session will block indefinitely waiting for the lock.

Comment: Thanks justin this seams great. But order of execution of update_pricerange also matter. So will waiting sessions get the locks in the sequence of  request? Thanx

Comment: @user621409 - Why does the order of the calls matter?  You're not passing any parameters to the procedure so how can you differentiate between two different calls to the procedure?  You realize that each job will run in a separate session with no idea which session spawned it and no ability to read uncommitted changes made by that parent session, right?

Comment: Yeah I didn't mention in question bt I am passing a number variable to update_pricerange.

Comment: @user621409 - What does that number represent?  Doesn't that cause the procedure to update a different set of rows?  Why does the order matter?  And what determines the order?  When the `dbms_job.submit` call was made?  When the calling transaction committed?  When the job was picked up and started?  When the call to `dbms_lock.request` was made?  There are lots of potential race conditions here before we get to the `dbms_lock.request` call.

Comment: Here number will be used for calculation purpose, same row will be getting updated .order is when the job was called. ..

Comment: @user621409 - If you want the procedures to execute in the order in which the `dbms_job.submit` calls were made, then `dbms_job` is the wrong approach.  The job cannot start until the parent transaction commits, which may be in a different order from the order in which calls are made.  There is no guarantee that the jobs will be run in the order that the calling transactions commit.  So even before you get to the implementation of your procedure, there are multiple things that could cause the order of operations to change.